# Saboteur 2 - How many saboteur cards do you take out for 4 players?

Tags: saboteur-2

I'm playing with 4 players in total in Saboteur 2 and we are not sure whether we are supposed to remove the other 2 Saboteur cards so that there is only 1 Saboteur.  I guess what I'm really asking is what's the exact preparation with 4 players in regards to which cards to leave in or take out for the Miners and the Saboteurs.

The way I understood it was to take out 2 of the 3 Saboteurs and leave the other miner cards in but there may be a chance that no one is a saboteur.  We then thought of taking out 2 of the 3 saboteurs but leave in only exactly 3 miners but the question then is how do you choose between 2 blue dwarves and 1 green or 2 green and 1 blue?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can see, in Saboteur 2 you never change the available roles based on the number of players. So in your 4 player game, you could have 3 Saboteurs and 1 Geologist, and a completely ridiculous mine in the end. The rules just say "Shuffle the 15 role cards together".

Comment: Thank you ConMan.  Because what happened was we had one turn where we had 3 Saboteurs and one miner and it just seemed so unfair in that case so I thought it would make more sense to take out the other 2 Saboteurs somehow?

Comment: There's a thread I found (and subsequently lost) on BGG where the designer points out that the increased variance, and particularly the possibility that everyone is actually working towards the same goal, is balanced by the gold distribution - the more players that win, the less gold that everyone gets. That said, you could probably take out, say, one of each of the more common roles, and not break anything horribly.

Answer (score 2):

**In a 4-player game, all 15 new Dwarf Cards are used.**

All 15 dwarf cards (4 green and 4 blue Gold Diggers, 1 Boss, 2 Geologists, 1 Profiteer, and 3 Saboteurs) are used, regardless of the number of players in the game. From the [rules](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Saboteur_2.pdf), under **Set-Up**

> [...] Then shuffle all 15 new Dwarf Cards and deal one face-down to each player. Again, **it does not matter how many players are taking part in the game**.